# Can someone check if my reasoning makes sense and if it sufficiently answers the question

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The question: Prove that if G is an open set that is dense in the metric space (S, d)
then (S − G) is nowhere dense in S

My answer: Suppose G is dense in (S, d). Then for an arbitrary non-empty open set A ⊆ S, A ∩ G ≠ Ø.
Let C = A ∩ G then C ⊆ G and C ∉ (S - G). By the arbitrariness of C, A ∩ (S - G) = Ø thus (S - G) is nowhere dense.

Comment: Here $a$ is a subset of $S$ and you are writing $a\not\in (S-G)$ as if you think that $a$ is now a point in the space $S$.  [Also don't drive us crazy by writing lower case for your new set when every other set here is in upper case.  If I am going to spend some time ruminating about the metric space $(S,d)$ then I would much prefer upper case $A,B,C,\dots$ for subsets of $S$ and $a,b,c, \dots$ for points in $S$.  Otherwise I get disturbed and refuse to play along.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple argument. S-G is nowhere dense if (definition) int(cl(S-G))=∅. Since S-G is closed this is int(S-G)=∅. Assume this is not true. Then there is an open set A such that A⊆S-G . But then A∩G⊆(S-G)∩G=∅. Which contradicts the fact that G is dense.